# Image not uploading for programatically created product

Tags: magento-1.8, image-upload

I am trying  below code to create product programtically , all is well, but if guest create product, than custom image not uploading

Can someone show me the right way ?

```
protected function _thisProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
        {

            // code for Guest

             $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                return;
            }

            $result = array(
                'success' => false
            ); 

         if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
                $productId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
               // echo $login['product_id'];die;
                if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                    try {

                          $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array('_secure' => true));
                        $result['success'] = true;
                        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

                // code for guest end       

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            //  custom product images

            $images = array(
                'thumbnail'   => 'image.png', // displaying under cart page
                //'small_image' => 'image.png',
                'image'       => 'image.png',  // displaying under my design
            ); 

            foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
                if($newImagePath != ""){
                    $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'one_two_three/quote/';
                    $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                }else{
                    $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/super/';
                    $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                }
                //echo $path."<br>";
                if (file_exists($path)) {
                    try {
                        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "No image path found : `{$path}`<br/>";
                }
            }

            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
           $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

            if ($doSave)
                $product->save();

            return $product;

            // code for guest users

            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        switch ($e->getCode()) {
                            case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                                $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.username');
                                break;
                            case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                                $message = $e->getMessage();
                                break;
                            default:
                                $message = $e->getMessage();
                        }
                        $result['error'] = $message;
                        $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::helper("ajaxlogin")->log("There has been an error during the login.");
                        // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                    }
                } else {
                    $result['error'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Login and password are required.');
                }
            }

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            // code for guest end
        }
```

BELOW CODE WORKING correctly for registered users :

```
   protected function _thisProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
    { 

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');   
        // product images

        $images = array(
            'thumbnail'   => 'image.png', // displaying under cart page
            //'small_image' => 'image.png',
            'image'       => 'image.png',  // displaying under my design
        ); 

        foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
            if($newImagePath != ""){
                $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'one_two_three/quote/';
                $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
            }else{
                $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/super/';
                $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
            }
            //echo $path."<br>";
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "No image path found dear: `{$path}`<br/>";
            }
        }

        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
       $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();           

        return $product;

    }
```

Updated question :

how to check `$newImagePath` variable sending the value or not ?

```
$newImagePath = $this->getRequest()->getParam("image");
```

Comment: may be u have missed the media gallery initialization,   $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) please add the same as shown in the screenshot http://prntscr.com/exeb7e

Comment: please check the same in this reference link http://prntscr.com/exebnx so that you will get an idea. update me thanks.

Comment: i am checking now sir.....

Comment: sir, i tried like this : `try {
     $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
     $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
    }` still the same result......

Comment: kindly check commas and semi columns and try it again.

Comment: is there any way  how to check  `$newImagePath = $this->getRequest()->getParam("image");` , here $newImagePath is sending value or not ?

Comment: i checked all semi columns and commas, looks its fine, please look at updated question once